# passing scope variable values to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three `scope` variables:

I am trying to pass the `scope` values to below object, but its failing and throwing me errors...

```
$scope.content.new_line = "'\n'";
$scope.content.text1 = "Text.\n\n";
$scope.content.text2 = "Text.\n\n";

var content = {
    pageSize: $scope.pageSize,
    content: [
        {
            text: "some text",
            style: ['header', 'aligncenter']
        },
        $scope.content.new_line,
        $scope.content.text1,
        $scope.content.text2, {
            style: 'center'
        },
        '\n',
        'Text.\n\n', {
            text: 'Again some text',
            style: ['quote', 'small']
        }
    ]
};
```

can anyone let me know how to pass the `scope` values to this `object` properly.

I am using `pdfmake` library... 
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Here is a normal content:

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    'paragraph 1',
    'paragraph 2',
    {
      columns: [
        'first column is a simple text',
        [
          // second column consists of paragraphs
          'paragraph A',
          'paragraph B',
          'these paragraphs will be rendered one below another inside the column'
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Care to share the error you're getting?

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: @DanielA.White: I have updated the post....

Comment: How is that "normal content" related to the problem? Please post the error messages and the lines where they point to.

Comment: If you're not going to clarify the question, please either post an answer (if you've solved it) or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$scope.content = {}
```

In the first line :>

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the difference between definition-time access to your `scope` rather than run-time access.

```
var scope = {value: 5};

var content = {
    value: scope.value
};

scope.value = 6;
console.log(content.value);
```

In the above snippet, the console log will show "5". This is because the scope value is assigned at definition-time. Here is an alternative:

```
var scope = {value: 5};

var content = {
    getValue: function() { return scope.value; }
};

scope.value = 6;
console.log(content.getValue());
```

Here the console log will show "6". I'm guessing this isn't the solution you are looking for, provide more details on how this data is created and accessed and the right solution might be more obvious.